# xhr.send(file) doesn't post it as multipart

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, google-chrome

On Firefox 3.6 and Chrome, using xhr.send(file) just puts the raw contents into the body of the request and it is not a true multipart/form-data upload.

Tried doing this: http://kaply.com/weblog/2010/05/20/post-multipart-form-xhr/

But, can't really mix string with File contents during send().

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`xhr.sendAsBinary()` is non-standard. Instead, use `xhr.send(FormData)`, which does create a `multipart/form-data` request, allows appending files, and arbitrary form data.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(file.name, file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data
```

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is using sendAsBinary(body) istead of send(body). See the last comment on the page you linked!